# How to write a replace a word from a text file and replace it?

Tags: python

i am a beginner of python. I am confused about replace sting. Suppose i have a invitation letter.How can i write a program which can ask the user name. and text will come out with this name. Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

```
'Hello yourname, welcome to stackoverflow. You should choose a friendly name'.replace('yourname', 'thank u')
```

`'Hello thank u, welcome to stackoverflow. You should choose a friendly name'`

Answer (score 0):

[The input Function](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html#the-input-function)

```
person = input('Enter your name: ')
print('Hello', person)
```